# Looping through a set of variables for R package analysis

Tags: loops

Here's a novice question..being new to R this has got to be.

I am trying to run an R package that analyzes "csv" data using the following R scripts:

> library(agricolae)
> LXTOUTPUT2<-with(RLINXTES2, lineXtester(Replication, Lines, Tester, Y))

All elements analyzed by the function "lineXtester" are numerics.

Analyzing 1 variable is fine. However, I have several variables to supply as "Y" and would like to run this through as one chunk.

I tried the "for loop" but couldn't find the right script that would cycle thru all variables.

Instead of "for loop" is there a better, faster option?  I read about "vectorizing" but R is still a strange stuff for me.

Would greatly appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My sincere apology.  I was finally able to figure out my problem by reading and learning more about "vectorization" and applying it to my dataframe and accessing the elements using the [[]] indexing.

Indeed, it is much simpler and faster than using the "for loop".

Please disregard my request for help.

Thank you just the same.